# NIO2 AsynchronousSocketChannel read/write fully using CompletionHandler

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I'm using java 7's nio2 AsynchronousSocketChannel to perform read and write operations using CompletionHandlers. Firstly I would like to know if a write operation is guaranteed to write out the ByteBuffer fully or not. If it's a partial write, using CompletionHandler's is there a way to fully write out the ByteBuffer. Maybe using recursion ?

Same goes for reading. I'm I guaranteed to read the whole message completely from the AsynchronousSocketchannel or can it be a partial read also. If so, again using CompletionHandlers how could I write a handler that would do a full read operation.

Thanking you in advance
Francis

Comment: There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It's a byte stream. Answer to both questions is therefore no.

Answer (score 1):

None of `read` and `write` operations are guaranteed to write or read full content of the buffer. They just read or write whatever is available in the underlying socket for the read operation or how much the operating system can put in a buffer for write operation.

To do full read/write reliably you need to repeat the `read`/`write` operation as long as there is some remaining space/bytes in the buffer:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(full_size_I_do_expect);
channel.read(buffer, null,
    new CompletionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
            if (result < 0) {
                // handle unexpected connection close
            }
            else if (buffer.remaining() > 0) {
                // repeat the call with the same CompletionHandler
                channel.read(buffer, null, this);
            }
            else {
                // got all data, process the buffer
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable e, Object attachment) {
            // handle the failure
        }
});
```

Comment: result = 0 doesn't mean connection close, 0 bytes may be read normally, -1 means connection close

Comment: @ArtyomNikolaev : well, not really normally, it can happen only in case when request for reading 0 bytes is placed. Which would mean usually bug in the program (probably resulting into infinite loop so it may be safer to kill connection anyway :-) ). But you're right, the comment about connection closed was not precise, I updated the code.

Comment: Isn't the `result == 0` just an indication that you're reading faster than you've received? I'm still working my way around some of this Async NIO code; but it would seem that if there's nothing to read yet it simply executes the completion handler with zero bytes. Does this then just loop until you get more bytes or until you get EOS?
The Java doc suggests this "Where r is 0, the read operation completes immediately with a result of 0 without initiating an I/O operation" [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html)